# How to set the class="active" to two separate links based on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

Trying to find a way to set a link as active for a navbar when a certain area of  the webpage is scrolled to in a one page site.

I have this working for my main menu that is seen by larger resolution displays, however I also have a secondary menu for mobile devices and despite all attempts it seems to never work. I have tried setting both or just setting the mobile by itself to no avail. Any help is appreciated below is a copy of my navbar code along with the java script to set active that I've used.

```
<!-- Start Header Section -->
<div class="hidden-header"></div>
<header class="clearfix">

  <!-- Start Top Bar -->
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- Start Contact Info -->
          <ul class="contact-details">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +1 (000) 000 0000</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> email@domain.com</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- End Contact Info -->
        </div>
        <!-- .col-md-6 -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- Start Social Links -->
          <ul class="social-list">
            <li><a class="facebook itl-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a class="twitter itl-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a class="google itl-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Google Plus" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- End Social Links -->
        </div>
        <!-- .col-md-6 -->
      </div>
      <!-- .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
  </div>
  <!-- .top-bar -->
  <!-- End Top Bar -->

  <!-- Start  Logo & Naviagtion  -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- Stat Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- End Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img alt="AltTxt" src="images/logo.svg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="menu-center" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <!-- Start Navigation List -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- End Navigation List -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
    <ul class="wpb-mobile-menu">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Mobile Menu End -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Header Logo & Naviagtion -->

</header>
<!-- End Header Section -->
```

And here is the javascript I've been using to modify the primary menu:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currentLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currentLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currentLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: Here's the new code I'm working with which is working for both menu's but not all sections.

```
    var navItems = jQuery('.menu-item a');
var win = jQuery(window);
var items = jQuery('.item');


navItems.click(function(e){
    var item = jQuery(this);

    jQuery('.menu-item a.active').removeClass('active');
    item.addClass('active');
});



win.scroll(function(e){
    jQuery.each(items, function(key, value){
        var item = jQuery(value);
        console.log(win.scrollTop(), item.offset().top);
        if(win.scrollTop() >= item.offset().top){
            jQuery('.menu-item a.active').removeClass('active');
            var id = item.attr('id');

            jQuery.each(navItems, function(key, value){
                var navItem = jQuery(value);
                if(navItem.attr('href') == '#'+id) navItem.addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) might help as it is hard to just dive into a wall of code.

Comment: A very minor comment (not directly related to your problem) but you could rewrite `$('a').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('active'); })` as simply `$('a').removeClass('active');`. They're identical in outcome

Comment: I found some other code that I have working for me part way. I'm having a bug with it not working for my "Home" section however. The reason I didn't post a fiddle before was because the work in progress is quite large especially the css and js. @freefaller ty for pointing that out it definately would have cleaned up the code some if I was still using that bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the error that was causing the new code to not entirely work. Go figure use another persons code and accidentally had a repeat class. For anyone else trying to do this the following works for me:

```
var navItems = jQuery('.nav-item a');
var win = jQuery(window);
var items = jQuery('.segment');


navItems.click(function(e){
    var segment = jQuery(this);

    jQuery('.nav-item a.active').removeClass('active');
    segment.addClass('active');
});



win.scroll(function(e){
    jQuery.each(items, function(key, value){
        var segment = jQuery(value);
        console.log(win.scrollTop(), segment.offset().top);
        if(win.scrollTop() >= segment.offset().top){
            jQuery('.nav-item a.active').removeClass('active');
            var id = segment.attr('id');

            jQuery.each(navItems, function(key, value){
                var navItem = jQuery(value);
                if(navItem.attr('href') == '#'+id) navItem.addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to set any menu item's `<li>` to `class="nav-item"` and set any `<section>` to `class="segment"`